# Display git branch in terminal

Tags: bash, git, prompt

I am using fedora OS and I want to display git branch or tag in terminal when I go into the git folder project.

I follow [this tutorial](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Git_quick_reference#Display_current_branch_in_bash). After I ran:

```
source /usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

It displays the git branch well. But if I run:

```
cd .. #I go back the parent folder which is not git folder
```

It keeps the git branch. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is strange. Can you show more details on your directories structures and the prompt diplsayed? After your change in `.bashrc` did you log out and in again ?

Comment: I've just read `/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`. Instruction about how enable this feature placed at the begin of file. Also, after instruction about enabling this feature the sentence **"# The argument to __git_ps1 will be displayed only if you are currently
# in a git repository."** is present. It's mean that feature must work right. Please try enable feature again following instructions in `git-prompt.sh`.

Comment: @GAVD: Did you set `GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO` to1 before sourcing?

Comment: you have a .git directory in parent directory, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how the tutorial is misbehaving, but you can do this yourself pretty easily. Define an alias like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
# function for PS1 to display [ git branch] when it is defined
function __show_git_branch() {
  branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null`
  test -n "$branch" && echo " [$branch]"
}
```

then set PS1 to something like this:

```
PS1='-- $(__show_git_branch) \$ '
```

This will cause the git branch to be recalculated every time the prompt is displayed. If there is an error, it is sent to `/dev/null` and the subsequent `test` will not echo anything, so that this will return an empty string if you are not in a `git` directory.

You did not ask this, but I pass it along as a "handy hint."  It can be helpful to know that you are re-initializing *everything* when playing with `bash` aliases and environment variables. A straightforward way of doing this is to use `exec`:

```
exec bash
```

This will re-start bash over the currently running shell.  If you want to restart it as if you were logging in again, then `exec bash -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Add these code lines in your `~/.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file

1. open the terminal. And go to your home directory in the terminal
   (which is denoted by `~`). You can go to the home directory using `cd`
   command and press the enter in terminal.
2. Now you type `la` and see, does .bashrc or .bash_profile exist.
3. Now open up any files using `sudo nano .bashrc` (here you can use
   either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`). I am using `.bashrc` file here

[image]

Now your nano editor will prompt, go to the bottom of your nano editor by pressing down-arrow key and paste the following code lines at the end of your file.

```
# to add the git branch names
function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
 
RED="\[\033[01;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[01;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[01;32m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[01;34m\]"
NO_COLOR="\[\033[00m\]"

# without host
PS1="$GREEN\u$NO_COLOR:$BLUE\w$YELLOW\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOR\$ "
# with host
# PS1="$GREEN\u@\h$NO_COLOR:$BLUE\w$YELLOW\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOR\$ "
```

[image]

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit from the nano editor.

Now you are done.

now check your git repository it will be shown the branch name with colourful names.

[image]

References

> https://gist.github.com/danielalvarenga/2df8cabbd6f3041c2378